# Верстка и REST API

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, rest

Во **flask** если реализовать **RestAPI** (скажем два namespaces - User и Posts, CRUD функции к каждому).

То я получаю результат -> могу через *url* так или иначе взаимодействовать с базой.

Вопрос: я не понимаю, как это использовать дальше, могу ли взаимодействовать с этим как верстальщик?

(например хочу свой блог, с кучей интерактива и т.п., несколько blueprints, рендерить кучу html соответственно - а как это объединять с restapi не понимаю, как отделить url blueprint'ов от namespace'ов, как то я запутался)

Подскажите плиз что дальше то, и вообще надо ли что то дальше делать, может идея не в этом.

Comment: Это всё надо делать не во фласке, а в браузере. Почитайте про SPA и связанные с ним штуки

Comment: (ну, как «надо»... лично я считаю, что SPA дерьмо и RestAPI тоже дерьмо, но большинство со мной не согласится)

Comment: я далек от мира web , это исключительно в образовательных целях.  что такое SPA - синг пейдж апп?

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете реализовать запрос к api через JS(например через fetch). Например: GET /api/v1.0/users

Почитать об этом можете тут: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch